# Why doesn't my user info transfer automatically from StackOverflow to Meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

I think it's silly that one has to specify one's name etc. again on Meta.

I don't care a whit about transferring of reputation etc., as I see "related questions" are concerned with, but I just flatly refuse to endlessly fill in my name & other details again and again.

Why hasn't this been fixed, or rather, why is it broken in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to your user profile on the site where you have your details filled in and look at the Accounts tab, you'll see a button letting you copy that profile to all your associated accounts.

Note:  This will not copy over your open-id information.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I checked if it could be done the other way, but apparently not (however, there was something that looked vaguely like a "down for maintenance" message, but not very clear). I think it should be THE OTHER WAY! :-) I'd accept your reply as the truly One And Only Correct Answer, except that I'm not allowed to do that until five minutes have passed. Which is about now, because the AntiVirus update kicked in, running Windows Update, which slows everything down to a craaaaaaawl. Argh! But thanks. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: @Alf, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66860/cannot-associate-meta-stackoverflow-with-other-sites-and-inbox-missing-on-meta) for details on why Meta associations are a *bit* broken right now.